# Node running Lua script for Redis. How to return sorted set from Lua script to Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lua, redis

This is the Lua script code in file test.lua:

```
local ips_key = 'production:ips'
local ids = redis.call('ZRANGE', ips_key, 0, '+inf', 'WITHSCORES')
local result = {}
for i, name in ipairs(ids) do
    table.insert(result, name)
end
return js.global:Array(table.unpack(result))
```

I'm using ioredis, which is a redis npm to eval this lua script. the return value is undefined. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share with us your javascript where you use/call your .lua script?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the above script.

L#2: [`ZRANGE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrange) does not accept `+inf` (or `-inf`) as arguments, the input should be indices in the sorted set - replace it with `-1` to retrieve the entire range of elements.

L#7: There's no `js` library in Redis' Lua so that won't work (and isn't needed anyway)

L#7: `table.unpack` is Lua 5.3, whereas Redis is 5.1 - use `unpack` instead when needed.

L#7: No need to `unpack` the result you're returning (if you do, you'll just get the first element in the array back and that's it)

L#1 I understand that this is a test, but always use the `KEYS` input table to pass your keys to the script - never hardcode/generate key names inside it.

All in all, this should "work" when called with a single key as input:

```
local ips_key = KEYS[1]
local ids = redis.call('ZRANGE', ips_key, 0, -1, 'WITHSCORES')
local result = {}
for i, name in ipairs(ids) do
    table.insert(result, name)
end
return result
```

As a final note, the code currently "works" but does nothing - it copies the results of the call to `ZRANGE` and returns them. Put differently, the reply is the same as just calling `ZRANGE` regularly w/o Lua.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I tried your script, and I'm getting this error: ReplyError: ERR Error running script (call to f_141e3442dff9d575f86f6a4a2e642ba1cf6abc01): @user_script:7: Script killed by user with SCRIPT KILL... ]. To be clear, I'm calling my lua script from node.js.

Comment: The error means someone (you?) killed the long running script. The bigger your sorted set is, the longer the script will run (and the more RAM that it will need).